# C++ no match for 'operator=' in '*foo

Tags: c++

```
Shape *foo = new Shape[2];
foo[0] = new Triangle();
```

Class Shape. Class Triangle inherits Shape, default constructor. I use the above in an effort to make the first element of foo Triangle and gives me:
`no match for 'operator=' in '*foo = (((Triangle*)operator new(20u)), (<anonymous>->Triangle::Triangle(), <anonymous>))'`
`candidates are: Shape& Shape::operator=(const Shape&)`

Comment: Do you want an array of `Shape`, or an array of `Shape*`?

Comment: an array Shape where I can cast first element Triangle and the second Rectangle...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type of `foo[0]` is `Shape`. You cannot assign a `Triangle*` to `foo[0]`. What you need is:

```
Shape** foo = new Shape*[2];
foo[0] = new Triangle();
```

Make sure you delete the contents of `foo` before you call

```
delete [] foo;
```

**A Better Alternative**

Use a `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr`s.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> foo;
foo.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Shape>(new Triangle()));
```

Then, you don't have to worry about deallocating memory explicitly. `std::vector` will take care deleting `std::unique_ptr`s. When the `std::unique_ptr`s are deleted, they will delete the objects they are pointing to.

Comment: Please don't teach people to use built-in arrays and raw pointers and `delete`.

Comment: I would strongly prefer `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>>` as it will manage the lifetime of the array and object allocations automatically.

Comment: @cdhowie, I was updating the answer to use exactly that while you were writing the comment.